# Hashmap list updating all string values

Tags: java, android, hashmap, expandablelistview

I am using expandable list view and need list of headers and child of each header...the problem i am facing with below code is that it is updating all string/key values instead of targeted one...

```
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        databaseProjects = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayListTagNames=new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayListTagNames.clear();
        int countheaders = 0;


        for(int i = 0; i < databasePositions.size(); i++) {


            if (!(databasePositions.get(i).equals("None"))) {

                listDataHeader.add(databasePositions.get(i));

                databaseProjects = databaseAdapter.getAllProjectsNameOnlyDBusingserverID(databasePositionsid.get(i));

                for (int j = 0; j < databaseProjects.size(); j++) {
                    if (!(databaseProjects.get(j).equals("None"))) {
                        arrayListTagNames.add( databaseProjects.get(j));
                    }
                }

                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(countheaders), arrayListTagNames);


                countheaders++;
                arrayListTagNames.clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're only creating a single `ArrayList<String>`, then putting a reference to that list in the map multiple times. Basically, you need to create a new list on each iteration.

Comment: but i am clearing each time and adding updated list only to new positions but still it is replacing all?
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(countheaders), arrayListTagNames);

Comment: You're clearing *the same list* repeatedly. It's *vital* that you learn about how references work in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are clearing the arrayList using arrayListTagNames.clear() it affects the contents which are put in hashmap, Instead of clearing create a new array list and put in HashMap, try some thing like this

```
private void prepareListData() {
            listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
            listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            databaseProjects = new ArrayList<>();
            int countheaders = 0;


            for(int i = 0; i < databasePositions.size(); i++) {


                if (!(databasePositions.get(i).equals("None"))) {
                    arrayListTagNames=new ArrayList<String>();

                    listDataHeader.add(databasePositions.get(i));

                    databaseProjects = databaseAdapter.getAllProjectsNameOnlyDBusingserverID(databasePositionsid.get(i));

                    for (int j = 0; j < databaseProjects.size(); j++) {
                        if (!(databaseProjects.get(j).equals("None"))) {
                            arrayListTagNames.add( databaseProjects.get(j));
                        }
                    }

                    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(countheaders), arrayListTagNames);


                    countheaders++;
                }
            }
        }
```